# How does Chrome infer the type/name of an object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a React element in a variable. Chrome dev tools correctly identifies it as `element: input` but how does it get the string/value `input`?

```
element.toString() == "[object HTMLInputElement]"
element.constructor.name == "HTMLInputElement"
```

Comment: It shows `nodeName` when the object is a document node. You can dig devtools source code for the exact logic.